# Unable to update FIWARE cygnus

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I am trying to update cygnus to the last version.
My curent version is 0.13.

when I try to install cygnus-common and cygnus-ngsi I got the error no package is available:

```
$ sudo yum install cygnus-common
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Fiware                                                                                                                                                                             |  951 B  00:00:00
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr
 * extras: distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr
 * updates: mirror.in2p3.fr
No package cygnus-common available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

My Fiware yum configuration repo is under this file "/etc/yum.repos.d/fiware.repo"

```
[Fiware]
name=FIWARE repository
baseurl=http://repositories.testbed.fi-ware.eu/repo/rpm/x86_64/
gpgcheck=0
enabled=1
```

what have I missed? 
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pakages are now in the FIWARE repository. Specifically:

- cygnus-common_hadoopcore_1.2.1-1.2.0-0.gbd4790e.x86_64.rpm
- cygnus-ngsi-1.2.0-0.gbd4790e.x86_64.rpm

I.e. those about the 1.2.0 version of Cygnus.